# Does gcc 4.8.1 have C++11 support for garbage collection?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, garbage-collection

The reason I'm asking is, that there are contradictory pieces of information on the web. On the one hand on [isocpp.org](http://isocpp.org/) it states that GCC 4.8.1 has the C++11 standard implemented completely. On the other hand the [GCC C++11 support page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) states that there is no "Minimal support for garbage collection and reachability-based leak detection". So is GCC 4.8.1 really C++11 feature complete?

Comment: Isn't garbage collection optional?

Comment: Gcc 4.8 is fully compliant with C++11 at the core language level, which does not mean that the library implementation is fully compliant with C++11.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: GC is optional, minimal support for GC is not and is missing from gcc as of 4.8

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas But "Minimal support for GC" is listed as a language feature, not a library feature, at least on the GCC support page.

Comment: @jogojapan: There are different parts of the proposal, some are core language (slight modifications of what a *safely derived pointer* is, for example), others are interfaces to be added to the standard library (*Library Wording* section in the paper). A compiler that implements the core language appropriately but not the library does not implement the paper, yet it is fully compliant at the core language level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The support for garbage collection is optional by the standard (see [Bjarne Stroustrup C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#gc-abi)). Therefore, GCC 4.8.1 is feature complete since it implements all the mandatory core parts of the standard.

The comments proved my answer unclear, I will be more specific: I was only talking about the core support for garbage collection. The library part is mandatory. The version of libstdc++ shipped with GCC 4.8.1 is not fully C++11-compliant (`<regex>` is not currently working for example), and the ABI for garbage collection is part of the missing features.

Comment: +1, see [Proposal N2670](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2670.htm): *An implementation that does not support garbage collection and implements all library-calls described here as no-ops is conforming.*

Comment: Providing a GC is optional, providing *support* for a GC is not. The entry in the gcc c++11 status refers to the *support* for a GC, and it is not implemented. That is, using Syam's comment above: doing GC is optional (the calls can be no-op), but the interface must be present (this is not optional)