# Relaxed or strict pointer safety?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've come across with the `relaxed/strict pointer safety` concepts and that it is implementation defined whether an implementation has relaxed or strict pointer safety. My question is about modern implementations:
Does clang and g++ have strict or relaxed pointer safety?

I would like to clarify the following thing about strict pointer safety concept. There is a quote (sec. 3.7.4.3/4):

> Alternatively, an implementation may have strict pointer safety, in
>   which case a pointer value referring to an object with dynamic storage
>   duration that is not a safely-derived pointer value is an invalid
>   pointer value unless the referenced complete object has previously
>   been declared reachable (20.7.4).

That restriction is completely unclear for me. Moreover, I've tried to experiments with the concept with [cplusplus.com example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/undeclare_reachable/)

```
// declare_reachable / undeclare_reachable example
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
  int * p = new int (1);    // dynamic object

  std::declare_reachable(p);

  p = (int*)((std::uintptr_t)p ^ UINTPTR_MAX);  // scrambling p

  // dynamic object not reachable by any live safely-derived pointer

  p = std::undeclare_reachable((int*)((std::uintptr_t)p ^ UINTPTR_MAX));
  // p is back again a safely-derived pointer to the dynamic object

  std::cout << "p: " << *p << '\n';
  delete p;

  return 0;
}
```

The code even does not compile.

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd1a9a486c043959)

Comment: Sounds like it is saying C++ can use garbage collection.  Using the BDWGC malloc package, declare_reachable() would map to GC_add_roots().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17019192/560648

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stuff is to allow garbage-collected implementations, though I'm not aware of any compilers (at least in the mainstream) that make any use of this.

Ostensibly you can find out whether yours does, using [`std::get_pointer_safety`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/get_pointer_safety), but [this appears ill-supp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/422772c519682488)[orted as well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f17bbf7c8cf4578).

I'd say just ignore it.

Comment: That is, if implementation does not implements GC it is not necessarily for one to implement undeclare_reachable and declare_reachable.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Where in the standard is that stated? 20.6.4 certainly doesn't.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv The functions must be provided by a conforming implementation, though they can simply be no-ops if relaxed pointer safety is used.

Comment: @T.C. If so, I had to recieve linker error instead of compile-time error,

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: No, you're making assertions based on what this particular implementation is _doing_, not what it is _supposed to be doing_. You're also doing it wrong: a function that is a no-op does not result in a linker error. T.C. is correct: these functions must at least be provided and the compilers mentioned are non-conforming as a result.

Comment: That is, invokation of any no-op function shall produce compile time-erorr, shall it?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: What? Why would that be? `void foo() {}` Why should calling `foo()` result in a compilation error? _How could it_, even? The definition may not be visible until linktime or even runtime!

Comment: I'm confused. Why does example that I cited produce compile-time error?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Because the toolchains didn't bother to implement this functionality _at all_. They are non-conforming.

Answer (score 0):

From cppference.com's [C++ preprocessor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace)

has this predefined macro:
**STDCPP_STRICT_POINTER_SAFETY** (C++11)

expands to 1 if the implementation has strict std::pointer_safety 
(macro constant)

I suspect this might be implemented first (and set to 0) before they implement the library/compiler support.